# using jquery to select the right part of HTML in a text variable

Tags: jquery

I currently have a variable that has some html:

e.g.

```
var data = "<li>item1</li> <li>item2</li> <li>item3</li>"
```

How would I used jquery to select the text of the first li. rememeber that this is stored in a variable and not in the html in my web page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

like this

```
var data = "<li>item1</li> <li>item2</li> <li>item3</li>";
var text = $(data).first().text();
```

Comment: I'll upvote if you also provide a vanilla.js version too

Comment: for those who inquire, this is the way to do it in JQuery.